# How to use list elements when replacing strings in Python?

Tags: python, list

I'm using data from a CSV file in my Python program, and I'm facing a problem when trying to run each separate data piece in my program.

If I have a variable like this, which is simply a list of items from each cell in my CSV column:

```
name = [(x) for x in column_1]
#[Sarah, Thomas, Howard, Lisa]
```

I want to use individual elements further from this. If I want to replace a link with each name from my column_1 data, and generate a big list of new links, how would I go about doing this?

```
print(new_link)
www.Sarah.com
www.Thomas.com
www.Lisa.com
```

My code looks like this so far, but I'm having trouble replacing the list as simply individual element strings from the list:

```
link = 'www.hello.com'
new_link = link.replace('hello', [(x) for x in name])
```

Where am I going wrong? Would appreciate any help - thanks!

Comment: `[f'www.{x}.com' for x in name]`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do one replace call with 3 substitutions.  You need

```
new_links = [link.replace('hello', x) for x in name]
```

That will produce a list of three names.

Answer (score 1):

```
name = ['Sarah', 'Thomas', 'Howard', 'Lisa']
link = 'www.hello.com'
new_link = [link.replace('hello', x) for x in name]
print(new_link)
```

output:

```
['www.Sarah.com', 'www.Thomas.com', 'www.Howard.com', 'www.Lisa.com']
```